# Creating Amazon Quicksight datasets in code and using them through the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-quicksight

I'm creating datasources/ datasets in code (boto3) but these don't show up in the console.
Even though the datasets are listed with list_data_sets, they don't seem to be available in the console.

I need to be able to create all the necessary datasets in code and then be able to use these to create new analyses/ dashboards in the console.

I'm using the Standard Edition of QuickSight. 
Can this be done? Or, can it only be done in the Enterprise Edition? Or, not at all?

Thanks

Comment: I have created datasets via boto3 in Standart Edition. It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [QuickSight pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/quicksight/pricing/) "APIs" are not available in Standard Edition. Exactly what that means, I have no idea.

But, assuming it's possible to call `create-data-set`, one important thing to remember is that data set permissions are necessary in order for users to view them.

According to the [boto docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.create_data_set), these permissions should be included in the following schema

```
    Permissions=[
        {
            'Principal': 'string',
            'Actions': [
                'string',
            ]
        },
    ]
```

In my code, I use the following to share with the `all-users` group (note the group principal, replace `AWS_REGION` and `ACCOUNT_ID` with your values)

```
    Permissions= [
      {
        'Principal': 'arn:aws:quicksight:AWS_REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:group/default/all-users',
        'Actions': [
          'quicksight:DescribeDataSet',
          'quicksight:DescribeDataSetPermissions',
          'quicksight:PassDataSet',
          'quicksight:DescribeIngestion',
          'quicksight:ListIngestions'
        ]
      }
    ],
```

I believe the same can be done for individual users, with an ARN resource of `user/default/user.name` instead of `group/default/all-users`.

For data sources, the set of permissions that I use is

```
        'Actions': [
          'quicksight:DescribeDataSource',
          'quicksight:DescribeDataSourcePermissions',
          'quicksight:UpdateDataSource',
          'quicksight:UpdateDataSourcePermissions',
          'quicksight:DeleteDataSource',
          'quicksight:PassDataSource'
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Despite the fact it says 'APIs not available' they obviously are as I can successfully create and list my datasets using the aws-sdk.
I've tried upgrading the QuickSight instance to Enterprise and the datasets created via code (using the sdk) are still not visible.
QuickSight says that the default resource permissions allow all users access to all resources as default, however, I tried your suggestion of adding the permissions, but it didn't work:
The creation through code is still successful and they are listable, but still don't show up in the console.

Comment: @FredHeeks that's odd as I was experiencing exactly what you're describing and permissions fixed it. Are you targeting a group your user belongs to or just your user?

Comment: I'm just targetting my user. I've used list-users to make sure I've got exactly the right ARN, but they still don't show up in the console.
Do your code created datasets show up in your console?

Comment: @FredHeeks yes, they do after adding the permissions code. it's worth noting that the principal is the user's ARN and not the value that's returned by the list APIs called "principal" (confusingly).

Comment: I've been using the Arn from the list-users:
`{
    "Status": 200,
    "UserList": [
        {
            "Arn": "arn:aws:quicksight:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:user/default/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "UserName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Email": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Role": "ADMIN",
            "Active": true,
            "PrincipalId": "federated/iam/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
}`
not the `PrincipalId`

I'm using CustomSQL to irect query so it may be that.
I'll try with a simpler dataset to see if that works.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I've accepted your answer as I tried it again, checking all the parameters more carefully and yes, the datasets are now showing up in the console after adding my user permissions to the code.
Thanks again.